# How can I obtain the outer perimeter of characters in binary images in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, character

I need to get the outer perimeter edge of a character that's inside a binary image. I have an image of the letter `A`. This image is a binary matrix.  I have binarized the image and i have saved it in a 20 x 20 matrix. I want to get only the external "ON" pixels .

In summary, I have this image:

[image: original image]

... and I want this image:

[image: image that i want]

What's the best way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Funny thing, there's a function in Matlab called `edge`. That might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the image processing toolbox installed.  The example image you uploaded is RGB, and so there has to be some pre-processing that needs to be done.  First, read in the image, then convert the image to binary.

For what I'm proposing to work, object pixels need to be white and so you need to invert the image so that it's white text on a black background.  Once you do this, fill in any holes, find the perimeter then reinvert back to your original colour scheme.

You may also need to thicken the resulting perimeter because this only finds a 1 pixel wide boundary.  Your example shows that the perimeter is a few pixels thick.  A dilation with a square structuring element could help here.

```
%// Read in image, convert to binary and invert
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooWFP.jpg');
im = ~im2bw(im);

%// Fill in holes
im_fill = imfill(im, 'holes');

%// Find perimeter
out = bwperim(im_fill);

%// Expand the perimeter and reinvert
out = ~imdilate(out, strel('square', 5));

%// Show image
imshow(out);
```

We get this:

[image]

Comment: Nice result and explanation!